# How to disable lazy loading in NSTabViewController?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit, nstabviewcontroller

I am designing a SwiftUI wrapper for NSTabViewController with the toolbar style. I want it to be a drop-in replacement for TabView. TabView uses a modifier `tabItem(_:)` to specify the tab name and icon. So I designed a similar modifier for my own `ToolbarTabView`:

```swift
extension View {
    func toolbarTabItem(_ label: LocalizedStringKey, nsImage: NSImage? = nil, tooltip: LocalizedStringKey? = nil) -> some View {
        self.preference(key: ToolbarTabItemPreferenceKey.self, value: ToolbarTabItemPreference(label: label, nsImage: nsImage, tooltip: tooltip))
    }
}
```

I wrap each `View` in a `NSHostingController` and create a `NSTabViewItem`. Then I use `onPreferenceChange` to set the `NSTabViewItem`'s `label` and `image` property. Finally, I have a `NSViewControllerRepresentable` to pass my array of `NSTabViewItem` to a `NSTabViewController`. This all works well except for the following issue.

By design `NSTabViewController` will only load its first tab. This loads the first `NSHostingController` which lays out the first `View`. That calls `onPreferenceChange` and sets the `label` for the first tab. However, the remaining tabs are not loaded and therefore the `label` remains unset.

I know that I can re-design my APIs to pass in the labels and images explicitly and that works, but then how does Apple implement their `TabView`? They must have the same issue with the views being lazy loaded because the macOS implementation of `TabView` looks like `NSTabViewController`.

I think a workaround would be to force all the tabs to load, which is the title of this question, but I am open to other ideas as well.

Reference:

https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/blob/dev/Platform/macOS/ToolbarTabView.swift

https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/blob/dev/Platform/macOS/ToolbarTabViewController.swift

Answer (score 1):

Here is the dumb workaround I came up with

```swift
public class UTMTabViewController: NSTabViewController {
    public override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        for i in self.tabViewItems.indices {
            self.selectedTabViewItemIndex = i
        }
        self.selectedTabViewItemIndex = 0
    }
}
```

Basically I force load every tab once the view appears. I really hope there's a better answer than this but I'll leave it here just in case.